# How can I let Kinesis firehose send array of json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I set kinesis firehose to stream data to a http endpoint. But I found the firehose sends multiple json rather than a json array.

so the data I received in the http side is:

```
{
 "data": "..."
}
{
 "data": "..."
}
```

but my application is only accept a valid json payload which should be `[{},{}]` format. How can I make kinesis firehose to send a valid json array?

Comment: I think you could transform the data using lambda.

Comment: that will increase cost on lambda execution. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The best way would be for your endpoint to take the raw data and process it itself. Maybe this would be easier to implement then lambda?